# how to use redux js on client side with plain javascript

Tags: redux

I wan't to use redux js on client side and i searched but all i found are about server side or react .
how can use redux js with  plain JavaScript on client side ?
and some guide to how work with it.

http://redux.js.org/

Comment: take a look at this link https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/counter-vanilla/index.html
it is an example using redux with vanilla.js(plain javascript)

Comment: @Shafizadeh , I live in Tehran

Comment: @Shafizadeh for more connection , please write your email address . tnx

Comment: @Shafizadeh it's ok just write your Telegram Id  or Phone number .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this tutorials from Dan Abramov (redux creator) at egghead.

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree

At this tutorial he uses examples with vanillajs and reactjs.

This help me a lot, so I hope this will help you.